# How to extract all matches with regex in VSCode snippets and return them in a specific format?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I am trying to create a snippet that extract certain elements on the path to the file. A path may look something like this:

```
/src/routes/server/[region]/[serverno]/user/[id]/profile
```

I want the snippet to give the following output:

```
region, serverno, id
```

I have tried multiple ways to do it, but it always requires me to specify which element I want, and I cannot make it so that it matches ALL elements.

```
"${TM_FILEPATH/.*(?<=\\[)(.*?)(?=])(.*?)(?<=\\[)(.*?)(?=]).*/$1, $3/g}"
```

would produce:

```
serverno, id
```

given the example above.

This is a poor attempt at solving this issue, however this only works for the last 2 elements wrapped in [ ].

Is there a way to do this with VSCode snippets or is it necessary to use something else?

Comment: are the brackets part of the filepath

Comment: @rioV8 yes they are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try these

```
"${TM_FILEPATH/[^\\[]*\\[([^\\]]+)\\][^\\[]*/$1, /g}"
```

or

```
"${TM_FILEPATH/[^\\[]*\\[([^\\]]+)\\][^\\[]*\\[([^\\]]+)\\][^\\[]*\\[([^\\]]+)\\][^\\[]*/$1, $2, $3/}"
```

Comment: The first example works but adds a trailing comma, which isn't the biggest dealbreaker in the world. Thanks

Comment: @IWishIKnewMore first example works for more than 3 fields, you can get rid of the trailing comma by adding a few conditional replace fields, check if there is a next fields and add a comma if yes, it all depends on how often you need to use this.